# Unmet Peer Dependency kendo-angular-grid@1.8.0 with rxjs@5.5.5

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I'm getting

> npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@^5 <5.5, required by
>   @progress/kendo-angular-grid@1.8.0. It's weird that the lower version
>   of @progress/kendo-angular-grid@1.7.1 works ok with rxjs@5.5.5 with no
>   dependency error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look here: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/changelog/ you need to use the 2.0 version of the grid if you want to use rxjs >= 5.5

Comment: Thanks!  I just found that out a minute after I post my question. Thanks again!